# How to remove lines over text using Phlox theme with Elementor Pro?

Tags: headers, text

I have been struggling a lot trying to get rid of a line that appears over the text of my home page. I am using the Phlox theme updated and elementor Pro for full compatibility. I already went into the WP dashboard-Pages-Page layout to change from full width to right sidebar and the issue gets fixed, so I assumed it is a coding change in the theme itself.
[image]

So. Does anybody have any idea of how to change this little detail using code? I already tried some advices but not for this theme specifically.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! We love to help. Third party plugins and themes are off topic, they are better asked about at their developers' support routes. See wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't remove it with the theme, but with the style sheet. Put the cursor over the line/text, right click and select inspect element. In the inspector on the left side go with the cursor over the elements and select the text. Then on the right side there is a Layout button, click it and there will be kind of a box. Look for the line in that box. It looks like a border of 1px to me. If you find it remove the 1px and if the line is gone put your cursor over the border, look at the name and two rows on the left of Layout there is a rules button for the CSS of the page. Search for the name of the border and open your style.css, look for that name and change it from 1px to 0px.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already checked the site with inspector and there is nothing I can find related to this line. You can take a look if you want https://ignaciog1.sgedu.site/ , but I took my time to inspect all the details in the inspector tool and I literally don't find anything, not even a border px, everything is set to 0 px.

Comment: alright. unfortunately this comes up when accessing your website: "Apologies, we are busy updating our website.", so I can't look for it myself.